# How to cryptographically sign concatenation of public keys with openssl Ask Question

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to simulate the Station to Station protocol with OpenSSL. All the steps are clear but one. Specifically each user has to sign the concatenation of the public keys of the two users.

So if user A has public key KA and user B has public key KB then I have to compute sign(KA || KB). There is a well-known function to sign data but how do I concatenate the public keys files?

Right now the content of the files are as follows:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MEYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAB8DMgAEHCxKip7cFGTqXCV5NgPY8XcpAOPi68/6
IYmqHhsm1K2/gfvpBMCtj7HnUHj1WojM
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MEYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAB8DMgAEM8L5ntap4heeGVhQ7TEY3JVK+GX3J/7O
SPEhc6k8nc0NXQnlmqaho4lCqhAVENRr
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Should I just sign the file:

```
MEYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAB8DMgAEHCxKip7cFGTqXCV5NgPY8XcpAOPi68/6IYmqHhsm1K2/gfvpBMCtj7HnUHj1WojMMEYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAB8DMgAEM8L5ntap4heeGVhQ7TEY3JVK+GX3J/7OSPEhc6k8nc0NXQnlmqaho4lCqhAVENRr
```

which is the concatenation of both keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the parties agree upon what is signed and how it is formatted, it does not matter how the concatenation is done. I would include the BEGIN and END lines too, to help separate the parts from each other.

By the way, in the STS protocol I am familiar with does not include signing the concatenation of *public keys*. This question might also better belong on crypto.stackexchange.com than here.